# What does API v2 assets call return with "Enforced Tenant ACL result: false"

Tags: linkedin-api

We are making this call to v2 of the LinkedIn [API](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/C4E0BAQEaqefwpOeklA):

We get a 401 response that looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.vector.utils.logic.LogicLayerException: Enforced Tenant ACL result: false, for Tenant urn:li:digitalmediaTenant:11 and Method read_assets",
    "status": 401
}
```

I can confirm our app is approved for v2 endpoints. Has anyone else had this issue and if so, how did you resolve?

Comment: Are you looking to upload file to linkedin with API?

Comment: @augustinejenin I'm trying to get the url for an asset

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to include image or other media information in the response? This is the response you typically get when you are decorating a response with a digitalMediaAsset URN and you fail to include :playableStreams or :privatePlayableStreams in the projection.  For example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~))
```

will result in that 401 response. However,

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

Will succeed.

See https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/media-migration